# passing time from csv to mysql

Tags: python

I am unable to import time in to mysql database I am new to python and this is my code.I was able to get date from csv file but not the time. I am getting the  time as 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. this is my csv file

```
2880,H3KZV,2014/06/24 09:34:28,2014/06/25 09:34:28
2880,R9UZB,2014/06/24 10:34:05,2014/06/24 16:34:05

    for row in reader:
        print row
        try:
            (location_id, vrm, start_datetime,end_datetime) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row]
        except:
            print "Error with row: " % row

            tmp = start_datetime.split(" ")
        start_date = tmp[0]

       tmp = end_datetime.split(" ")
        end_date = tmp[0]

        tmp = start_date.split('/')
        tmp = end_date.split('/')

        iso_date = "%s-%s-%s" % (tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2])
        entryDatetime = "%s 00:00:00 " % iso_date
        expiryDatetime = "%s 23:59:59" % iso_date
        sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_and_display
            (plate, machine_id, ticket_datetime, expiry_datetime, ticket_name, ticket_price)
            VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (vrm, location_id, entryDatetime, expiryDatetime, "RINGOtest", 0)
        print sql_local
        cursor.execute(sql_local)
        curl = pycurl.Curl()
        body = Body()
   payload = [("fn", "addWhitelistEntryValue"),
            ("firstname", "WL"),
            ("startDate", start_date.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
            ("startTime", "00:00:00"),
            ("endDate", end_date.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
            ("endTime", "23:59:59"),
            ("vrm", vrm.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
            ("locId", location_id.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: looking through this again, there are several problems. You use `tmp` for everything so it gets overridden. For instance the `tmp = start_date.split(" ")` is immediately lost and the end date is used for both dates.

I would move to one of the other solutions but if you wanted to use the current method this might help.

At the moment you are not using the time from the csv file.
Where you declare `start_date = tmp[0]` also get the time, then add it in at the same time as the date.

Try something like the following (but with the error handling and other stuff back in):

```
for row in reader:
    (location_id, vrm, start_datetime,end_datetime) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row]
    (start_date, start_time) = start_datetime.split(" ")
    (end_date, end_time) = end_datetime.split(" ")
    entryDatetime = ("%s %s" %(start_date, start_time)).replace('/','-')
    expiryDatetime = ("%s %s" %(end_date, end_time)).replace('/','-')
```

Also worth noting, the try block your try/except should include the rest of the code. At the moment if the decode fails, the rest of the code will still try and run but fail (or worse, re-enter the previous row).

Comment: That resolved the problem thanks a lot.... YOu made my day.... I was struck with this from last 48 hrs.

Comment: @shruthi see my edit, there are a couple of other issues you might run into.

Comment: `(location_id, vrm, start_datetime,end_datetime,ticket_price) =  ticket_price = int(ticket_price)/100 ;and in the function  ("ticket_price", ticket_price.encode('ascii', 'ignore')) how can i add ticket price in my query as i have ticket-price in csv like 1380=13.80`

Comment: @shruthi can you add this to your question? The formatting of comments means I can't see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date and time using `datetime` module

```
import datetime

start_datetime = '2014/06/24 16:34:15'
start_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_datetime, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print start_datetime

2014-06-24 16:34:15
```

---

**EDIT:** probably you could use MySQL to convert date and time: [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES( STR_TO_DATE('2014/06/24 16:34:15', "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") );
```

Comment: STR_TO_DATE is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Its because you defined them both with

```
entryDatetime = "%s 00:00:00 " % iso_date
expiryDatetime = "%s 23:59:59" % iso_date
```

Comment: if i take them out its displayed as 00:00:00  in time thats where i am struck i dont understand how to pass csv time values...